# navigation.clipboard.read() doesn't work in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, clipboard

I want to get the last image copied to clipboard, in localhost it works but in AWS Elastic Beanstalk application it doesn't.

> ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'read')

My code:

```
try {
      const clipboardItems = await navigator.clipboard.read();
      for (const clipboardItem of clipboardItems) {
        const imageType = clipboardItem.types.find((type) =>
          type.startsWith("image/")
        );
        const blob = await clipboardItem.getType(imageType);
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
        const image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = imageUrl;
        image.style.width = "100%";
        image.style.marginBottom = "15px";
        img_div.appendChild(image);
        modal_centered.appendChild(img_div);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.name, err.message);
      alert(
        "Error in capturing image from clipboard, try to add the image again"
      );
    }
```

I read that the NavigationAPI only works in HTTPS servers, but my EB instance and localhost, which the feature is working, are HTTP.

I really do have to change my EB instance to HTTPS? or there's a simple way to solve this issue? Because to change it, I have to get a certificate and a do a lot of stuff, so I don't want to do it and realize that there was another easier way.